# How to merge mutliple docker-compose files with extension fields and yml anchors?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create a base docker file with default configurations, and merge it with environment specific configs:

`docker-compose.base.yml`:
x-defaults: &my-defaults
volumes:
....
healthcheck:
test: ...

`docker-compose.prod.yml`:
version: '3.7'

```
services:
  hello-docker:
    <<: *my-defaults
    image: ...
    ports: ...
```

But when I run the `docker-compose config` command, I get an error:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml config`

Result:

```
yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'my-defaults'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 9
```

So is merging not possible with anchors?

Answer (score 1):

I guess TS no longer needs the answer, but in case other people like me will find this question important, Compose now has new feature to include files: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/14-include/

**compose.yml**

```
include:
  - another_file.yml

services:
  a:
    image: hello-world
```

**another_file.yml**

```
services:
  b:
    image: hello-world
```

These two will effectively merge into two-service compose file with just a single `docker compose up`  (no need to pass additional files via `-f`)

Answer (score 0):

A YAML anchor is local to a single file.  So no, you can't define an anchor in one file and reference it in another file.

Since Compose will merge settings when you use [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/), you don't really need to do this, though.  If your base `docker-compose.yml` file says

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: registry.example.com/app/${APP_TAG:-latest}
    healthcheck: { ... }
```

and then your development `docker-compose.dev.yml` says

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

then it will inherit the `image:` name and `healthcheck:` settings if you have both `docker-compose -f` options.

Comment: That doesn't help: I don't want to name all of my implementing services `app`. I want to define a global config that I could inherit to *multiple* services, of course with different names.